# typescript how to add new item to the beginning of an array

Tags: typescript, angular

I used array.unshift() with my Angular2 project. And I got

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined.
```

Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. Why array.unshift() is not recognized?

How can I add new item to the beginning of an array with Typescript?

Comment: Are you sure that your array is not `undefined`? Can you show us more code please?

Comment: Including the actual code would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error is saying that whichever identifier you are trying to invoke unshift() on actually has the value 'undefined' instead of array.

It's like if you were doing this:

```
var array = undefined;
array.unshift();
```

when you actually want this:

```
var array = [];
array.unshift();
```

double check that you are initializing your array correctly.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I used array.non-exist-property.unshift(). Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

The error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined.

Means that the "array" instance in context is actually `undefined` at the time of the execution of the invocation of the `.unshift` method. This error is raised when the method is attempted on an `undefined` variable. That is the root issue.

Once you correctly declare and instantiate the array, you should use `slice`.

Instead of:

```
let myArray;
```

Declare, and or instantiate:

```
let myArray: number[] = [];
```

Then you can add values and you could expect that at runtime array members would be available.

Rather that `unshift`, you are looking for the native array [`slice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method. Since **JavaScript** is valid **TypeScript**, this is simple. Here is an example:

Comment: +1, but FYI: The last sentence of your answer states _"Here is an example:"_, but no example is provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
let fruits = ["Banana", "Cherry"]
fruits.unshift("Apple")
```

>["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]